# JPA: Store fileAttachment into the database

Tags: mysql, jpa, attachment, playframework

I would like to know if there is any way I can store a fileAttachment directly into the database with JPA.

I have an attribute:

```
public fileAttachement logo;
```

I have tried to change it to:

```
@Lob
public byte[] logo;
```

But that's not doing what I was expecting.

Comment: `@Lob byte[] logo;` is exactly right. It would help if you could state what you were expecting and what the problem is. With code, preferably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And a "fileAttachment" is what exactly ? class definition ?
DataNucleus provides a flexible way of persisting *any* type as a String, so depending on your "fileAttachment" you could use that

Comment: This is the api page for fileAttachment : http://www.playframework.org/@api/play/db/jpa/FileAttachment.html

Comment: I have had a look at DataNucleus it seems good but I'd rather store my data as Blob.